# Reorder linq list within a inherited collection in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a class which contains the different zone

```
Public Class CollectionZone
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ClassZone)
' ....
End Class
```

and the second class :

```
Public Class ClassZone
    Public Property debutXMetres As Double
End Class
```

I'd like to reorder with that property, I tryed

```
dim collection as new CollectionZone
'init collection
collection = cType(collection.OrderBy(Function(obj) obj.debutXMetres).ToList(), CollectionZone)
```

but I have a invalid cast. How can i recover the CollectionZone class ?

Regards

Comment: Tried your code, did not get any exception.

Comment: strange. did you put some object within the collection ? i have a invalid cast exception

Comment: oh i got it. I'll add the code with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to cast `List(Of ClassZone)` to `CollectionZone` which is not possible. 
But rather than creating a new collection you can sort the one you have:

```
collection.Sort(Function(x, y) x.debutXMetres.CompareTo(y.debutXMetres))
```